# Does adding a number of bitmap draws on a canvas delay an earlier line draw?

Tags: wpf, canvas, bitmap, line, delay

I've read a bit about delays in WPF drawing. Before, I make a video and post some code I thought I would describe what, to me, is a very unusual experience. I've got some code that allows the user to draw a shape on the screen (which looks like old paper). When the user lets up on the left mouse button it automatically connects the last point to the first point like so:
[image]

BUT, when I uncomment the rest of the code (which occurs AFTER the call to close the poly with a line from the last point to the first point) and I do a modified scanline fill and fill in the shape with random tree objects so it looks like this:

[image]

**There is a *real noticeable delay* before the last line that closes the poly is drawn and the filled poly is displayed.**

This is what's really weird: adding a bunch of bitmap draw calls AFTER the last line call somehow delays the drawing of the earlier line call.

Is this some weird effect of how WPF draws lines and blits bitmaps? By the way, everything is on a canvas. I've added a bunch of

```
MainCanvas.InvalidateVisual();
```

But, it had no effect.
Is this just something that has to be lived with when using WPF?

Comment: You would have to show us (the relevant parts of) your code.

Comment: I've just added a Yes/No confirm MessageBox which kinda solves the problem. Mostly, I'm just making the observation of this weird WPF behavior. It's like WPF is not executing the last                 MainCanvas.Children.Add(line); until it completes the bitmap blits.